Translate global position into screen position taking into account camera zoom
I have a big 2D map. I need to move the player's cursor to a specific place on this map. And I know for sure that this place is currently visible on the screen.
I'm going to translate the position of this place on the map to a position on the screen and then use Viewport.WarpMouse(localPos) to move the cursor there.
I use the formula: globalPosition - Camera2D.GlobalPosition + GetViewportRect().Size / 2f; and it works fine when Camera2D.Zoom == 1. But if the zoom is different - it doesn't work.
I can't figure out how to take into account the camera zoom.

Solution is to multiply found offset by zoom:
(placePosition - _camera.GlobalPosition) * _camera.Zoom + GetViewportRect().Size / 2f;

